# What requirements should my App meet in order to be accepted into Ubuntu App Store?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

This question attempts to identify the constraints an Ubuntu (Touch) App should consider, in order to be accepted by the App Store.

- Should it be stable not beta?
- Should it not allow users to download copyrighted material? (from Youtube like services)
- Is advertising allowed?
- Is it compulsory to follow [Ubuntu App Design Guidelines](http://design.ubuntu.com/apps)?
- Is compulsory to develop an app which is capable of converging across devices?
- Is it compulsory to provide compiled binaries for all cpu architectures?
- Is there any kind of content the app should not deliver?

Answer (score 0):

First off, development of an app for smart phones will be a bit different.  However, most program development rules will still apply when it comes to content, ad delivery(if you chose to) what stage you want to release the app to and where you want it targeted.  Because of the limited (yes smart phones still have a slight minority demographic) range your app will follow, do make it available to as many devices as possible.  Guide lines should be followed as a guide, but remember they are publishing your stuff so do not stray too far.  As far as DRM is considered, a touchy yet still nasty subject.  Getting permissions first is a must.  Yes make as many arch complied sources, the more the merrier.

You are the developer, you want as many people as possible to know your app exist and that it is the best.